# Reducing the depth of a Hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hash object from an ActiveRecord.  I'm going to be calling `to_json` on it, but I am looking to reduce the depth of the object that is being returned.  Here is what my find looks like:

```
@tags = Tag.find_all_by_type("some_type", :select => :name)
```

The result of `@tags.to_json` looks like this:

```
[{"tag": {"name": "some tag name"}},
 {"tag": {"name": "another tag name"}},
 {"tag": {"name": "etc..."}}]
```

However, I want the result to look like this since I don't need each object wrapped in a `tag` object:

```
[{"name": "some tag name"}, {"name": "another tag name"}, {"name": "etc..."}]
```

Is there a way I can do this through a `map`, `collect`, or similar call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the variable `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` to `false`, you will get the behavior you are looking for.

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html)

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Although it's probably not the right thing to do, I set the value in the specific view where I need this to happen.  I didn't want to negatively effect any other calls in the project where others might expect the root in JSON.

Comment: That's true. I would recommend changing it back to the default of 'true' when you are done with your non-root JSON.

Comment: Tag.include_root_in_json = false  # Less chance of messing up other code. I really wonder why they didn't just let you specify this in the option hash passed to the #to_json method.

Comment: Nice find Lars, that is definitely a much better idea than to set the global. And, it does seem like that should be an option.